# SQL Number Formatting

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, number-formatting

I'm looking to use SQL to format a number with commas in the thousands, but no decimal (so can't use Money) - any suggestions?

I'm using SQL Server 2005, but feel free to answer for others as well (like MySQL)

Answer (score 4):

With TSQL you could cast to money and convert it will add the .00, but you could use replace or substring to remove.

```
replace(convert(varchar, cast(column as money), 1), '.00', '')
```

In SQL 2005 you could use a CLR function as well

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
public static SqlString FormatNumber(SqlInt32 number)
{
    return number.Value.ToString("N0");
}
```

and call it as any other user-defined function

```
SELECT dbo.FormatNumber(value)
```

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, the [`FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format) function will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle you can specify a format parameter to the to_char function:
TO_CHAR(1234, '9,999')  -->  1,234

Answer (score 2):

Any specific reason you want this done on the server side?  Seems like it is a task better suited for the client/report.

Otherwise, you are **storing a number as a string** just so you can keep the formatting how you want it -- but you just lost the ability to do even basic arithmetic on it without having to reconvert it to a number.

If you're really determined to do it in SQL and have a justifiable reason for it, I guess my vote is on Scott's method: Value --> Money --> Varchar --> Trim off the decimal portion

-- Kevin Fairchild

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server, you could format the number as money and then delete the right-most three characters.

```
replace(convert (varchar, convert (money, 109999), 1), '.00','')
```